# NoSQL — Database Design for a tracking application

Tags: database, nosql

I’m starting a new mobile project. I can’t figure out the best way to model my data using NoSQL (trying to use DynamoDB). Imagine I have an application very similar to MyFitnessPal.

You have a record of different foods. You have a bunch of users. You have the ability to track on a daily basis which food and how much of each was consumed by a user. Also, says the user has the ability to create custom foods (that can also be logged). Also, the user can create recipes that are made up of many different foods.

What is the best way to design the data model for tracking each log the user has made. This will be a very common query in the application where I want to know:
For a given day, which foods (and how much of it) did a particular user consume.

I care most about read performance to be able to know what my daily log was for a user. Do I need to have a second document to map the relationships between what foods and how much of it a given user had? What about for the custom foods, should they just go in a foods documents and assign a userID to it if the food is custom?

Comment: It seems that you are handling case where regular relation database can help. Why are you interested in solving it using NoSQL?

Comment: From what I understand NoSQL offers really fast reads and I wanted to explore using a NoSQL DB for once. I’m worried that even if I use a relational DB then I’ll sacrifice performance reading all the data from those tables since I’ll have to do a few JOINS to get all the data I need